# Proving $|\int_{C}f(z)\, dz|\leq10M$ when $|f(z)|\leq M$ on $D=\{|z|=50\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I am trying to solve a question from my complex analysis test that
I didn't manage to do during the test in order to practice for the
next exam.

The problem is as follows:

> Let $f:\,\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be analytic function. Assume that
>   $|f(z)|\leq M$ for every $z$ s.t $|z|=50$.
>
> Consider the upper half of the ellipse $C=\{2x^{2}+y^{2}=50|\,
>  y\geq0\}$.
>
> Prove $|\int_{C}f(z)\, dz|\leq10M$

**What I tried:**

Since $f$ is analytic, if $|C|\leq L$ then if $|f(z)|\leq M$ on
$C$ we get that $|\int_{C}f(z)\, dz|\leq ML$.

We also know that $$\max_{z\leq50}|f(z)|=\max_{z=50}|f(z)|\leq M$$

If $$2x^{2}+y^{2}=50$$ then $$x^{2}+y^{2}=50-x^{2}\leq50$$ hence for
every $z$ on $C$ we have $|f(z)|\leq M$.

From here I believe it only remains to show $|C|\leq10$ which I am
unable to do.

Can someone please help me out ? I guess that I am on the right track,
but I couldn't bound $|C|$ from above by $10$

Comment: Maybe as an alternative way to do the question, but could you not just try and use the inequality relating the modulus of an integral to the integral of the modulus of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma(t) := t$ for $t \in [-5,5]$. $C + \gamma$ is a closed path, hence
 $$\int_{C} f(z) \, dz + \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = 0$$ by Cauchy's integral theorem. Thus $$\left| \int_C f(z) \, dz \right| = \left|\int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz \right| \leq M \cdot |\gamma| = 10 M$$

---

Actually, it's impossible to prove $|C| \leq 10$. To find a lower bound for $|C|$ calculate the length of the red path:

$\hspace{80pt}$ [image]

By Pythagorean theorem, this length is equal to $$2 \cdot \sqrt{5^2+\sqrt{50}^2} = 2 \cdot \sqrt{75} \approx 17,32$$

Hence in particular $|C| >17$.